# Retrieval of signer

Tags: solidity

What are the values of v,r,s in ecrecovery?

```
function dsign(bytes32 hash) public constant returns(bytes32){
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(prefix, hash);
    return prefixedHash;
}

function verify(bytes32 _message, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) constant returns (address) {
    address signer = ecrecover(_message, _v, _r, _s);
    return signer;
}

function recovery(bytes32 _messagehash,uint8 _v,bytes32 _r,bytes32 _s) constant returns (address){
    address signer = ecrecover(_messagehash,_v,_r, _s);
    return signer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## ECDSA verify function

The `ecrecover` function is an implementation of the [ECDSA signature verification algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_verification_algorithm) that instead of returning a public key, returns the address of the signer's key instead.

The `r` and `s` parameters are the two curve parameters, which were used to sign, and `v` is the signature version.

The `r`, `s` and `v` values can be decoded from the signature itself, `r` is the first 32 bytes of the signature, `s` is the next 32 bytes, and `v` is the final byte.

In older code `v = 0` corresponds to a version `27` signature and `v = 1` corresponds to version `28`, although most modern code should be encouraged to use the correct version numbers.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer. If not let me know so I can further assist.